# Questions about proving $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, functions, trigonometry

$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$

Firstly, in the book, $\sin(x):=\sum_0^\infty (-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$

and then it claims $\frac{\sin x}{x}=1-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\dots=1-x^2(\sum_0^\infty (-1)^n\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n+3)!})$

then it says

> The power series in parentheses has infinite radius of convergence (why?), so
>   it defines a continuous function with value $\frac{1}{6}$ at $x=0$

I know the radius is infinity by ratio test, but why does convergence implies continuity? I know there are examples of continuous functions converge to an uncontinuous function.

Ex. $f_n(x)=x^n$ in $[0,1]$ converge to an uncontinuous function.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't say at $n=0$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series: The series converges ... **uniformly** on every compact subset of {x : |x − c| < r}.

Comment: @John Douma It does say at x=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general result: let $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$ be a power series with radius of convergence $R>0$, where $R= \infty$ is allowed.

If $0<r<R$, then the power series converges uniformly on $[-r,r].$ Since the functions $a_nx^n$ are continuous, $f$ is continuous on $[-r,r].$ Since $r$ with $0<r<R$ was arbitrary, $f$ is continuos on $(-R,R)$.

In your example the sequence $(f_n)$ does not converge uniformly.

Comment: Sorry I am still a little bit confused. How do I know if fn are uniformly continuous and fn converge to f then f is continuous?